# Positive Linear Functional on $C_b(X)$ is continuous.(Proof)

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

[image]

Firstly I think there is a mistake in the definition of sup norm. It should be defined with sup and not inf.(if not can someone provide a proof that works with the inf definition.)

Hence $\forall f\in C_b(X)$ $\forall x \in X$ $|f(x)|\leq ||f||_{\infty}$

Therefore, $||f||_{\infty}*1-f\geq 0$ and $||f||_{\infty}*1+f\geq 0$

This means that $L(||f||_{\infty}*1-f)\geq 0$. Hence $||f||_{\infty}L(1)-L(f)\geq 0$

Similarly:$L(||f||_{\infty}*1+f)\geq 0$. Hence $||f||_{\infty}L(1)+L(f)\geq 0$

Therefore,$|L(f)|\leq||f||_{\infty}L(1)$

Since $L$ is bounded L is continuous.
Is this proof sound?

Comment: Yes, it should use sup.

Comment: Please make questions readable without images.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks so in that case is the proof sound?

Comment: @JhonDoe Your proof is correct.